# What equipment (Antenna-Router) do I need for connecting to nearby WIFI routers?

Tags: wifi, router, wireless

Currently I have WIFI Parabolic (Grid) 2.4Ghz antenna 24dbi connected to my router that acts as WISP, I'm getting trouble at pointing antenna to the right direction. Signal is very unstable.

The WIFI I want to connect to is about 30 meters away and it is a regular home router.

Is there a better equipment for this purpose? I know these antennas are meant to work point-to-point

Comment: WiFi is a two-way connection so that "home router" probably has lower gain omnidirectional antennas and it's not going to throw signal to your parabolic dish antenna as easily as yours can throw back. 30m is not too far for a "home router" if there is line of sight, but multiple walls or objects in the way will decrease signal strength quite a bit. Also the path that the signal takes to your antenna might be un-intuitive because signals can reflect and cause interference patterns with themselves. A parabolic dish is best for straight line of sight between two points.